# How to tell user to input integer when they try to input letter?

Tags: java

The question has been answered, so thank you very much.I couldn't get the input to work but in the end I was able to. I end up using the hasnext code to get it so thank you very much.

```
 enter codint[] A= new int [10];
   int[] B= new int [10];
   int[] C= new int [10];
   int[] D= new int [10];
   int[] E= new int [10];
   int counter=0, ran_num1,ran_numb,avg;
   while(counter<10){
       ran_num1=  (int)(Math.random()*100 + 1);
        ran_numb= (int)(Math.random()*100 + 1);
        A[counter]=ran_num1;
        B[counter]=ran_numb;
        C[0]= A[counter]+ B[counter];
        D[counter]=B[counter];
        E[counter]= A[counter] + B[counter] + C[counter] + D [counter];
        counter++;}
    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++ ){
        System.out.println(D[i]);      }e here
```

Comment: like this:  `System.out.println("Please input an integer and not a letter.");`

Comment: Probably instead of input.nextInt(); use int x = Integer.parseInt(input.next())  arraye[j] = x; and throw a try catch block catching the exception and printing the above comment

Comment: sorry if ik kinda vague new at this but what i mean is, if the program asked you to put in 10 integers to find the average but you put in a letter instead how do i make it so that istead of showing up as a error it just tells the user to try again but use itegers this time.

Comment: @programmer2015 Sam I am is kidding I am sure he looked and realized you know how to println... Read my suggestion it might be more helpful

Comment: @programmer2015, so... which part do you not know how to do?  1.  Detecting whether the user entered an integer or some other character?  2.  Continuing to ask the user for input until they enter valid input?  3.  Tell the user to input an integer instead of a letter?

Comment: thanks to everone who has helped out, i eventually figured it out but i do have one more question if the user inputed for example 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 how could i get the program to repeat the number he inputed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you Input an `int` using `Scanner`, use the `.nextInt()` and use `hasNextInt()` to check.Heres how to use it:

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
int I;
do{
  System.out.println("Enter an Int");
  scan.next();
} while(!scan.hasNextInt());
   I= Scan.nextInt();
```

More Info here : http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29

Answer (score 0):

Well... I will keep it simple and answer "How to get integer input from user" with a simple program.

Basically... when you Scanner encounters some un-acceptable input... it throws a `java.util.InputMismatchException`... so just watch for it.. and retry if you see this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException

class GetIntegerInput {

    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        int iWantThisAsInt = iWillReturnIntFromInput();
    }

    public static int iWillReturnIntFromInput() {
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
         System.out.print("Please enter an integer :: ");
         try {
             int returnInt = scanner.nextInt();
             return returnInt;
         }
         catch( InputMismatchException e  ) {
             System.out.println( "Sorry. That does not look like an integer, Lets try again." );
             iWillReturnIntFromInput();
         }
         catch( Exception e  ) {
             System.out.println( "Some Other exception... Lets try again." );
             iWillReturnIntFromInput();
         }

    }

}
```